# Can I still use bridging header for cocoa pod frameworks?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I used to download Parse frameworks and bridge to my Swift project using bridging header file with this line:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

Now I just switched to use cocoa pods and things get messed up when I include use_frameworks! in the Podfile. If I keep using the same bridging file, all of the PFObjects become unresolved identifier when build, with error like "Use of unresolved identifier 'PFUser'". This error goes away when I put

```
import Parse
```

at the top of each file. But that is pretty much every file since it is a Parse project, let alone other things to import such as ParseUI etc. Is there a way to import once for all as the bridging header used to do?

I tried to change the import line in the bridging header to:

```
import "Parse.h"
```

It gives me another error saying "duplicate interface definition for class 'Parse'":

```
MyApp/Pods/Parse/Parse/Parse.h:66:1: error: duplicate interface definition for class 'Parse'
@interface Parse : NSObject
^
/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-dbdwtdjelpuomaaawugvjubngrvq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Parse.framework/Headers/Parse.h:66:12: note: previous definition is here
@interface Parse : NSObject
           ^
```

I checked other questions here but got no luck.
Any help?

Edit: this weird error is shown in picture here: Xcode identified the class but the app cannot compile. 
[image]

Comment: Yes still you have to use Bridging header and import like this `#import <Parse/Parse.h>`

Comment: See the issue I have. It gives me error that PFUser, PFObject become unresolved identifier if I import like that #import <Parse/Parse.h>

Comment: add your framework again.It should work.

Comment: What do you mean adding Parse framework again? It is added by  Pod install, isn't it?

Comment: My be it is not added successfully.

Comment: This may help you: http://shrikar.com/integrate-parse-with-swift-in-ios8-using-cocoapods/

Comment: Thanks. That was what I did but it didn't work for me, keeping giving me error like "Use of unresolved identifier 'PFUser'"

Comment: do you add your header file into build Settings -> swift compiler - code generation?

Comment: Yes, I did. Everything was working before I switched to cocoa pods instead of downloading Parse SDK and dragging to my project.